# Prevent or handle the selectAll action on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, select, input

I'm trying to release the following thing:
I have an input field in which users can type their phone number.
The first 3 characters are fixed in the inputfield, but can be changed with a dropdown-box.
e.g. +32 xx xx xx xx (the +32 can't be changed -> prevented with JS)

My solution is still not completely fail-proof, but my main problem right now is that i need to prevent the select of the first three digits...

Therefor I've typed this code (JQuery):
    `loginMobileInput.select(function(e){
        if (loginMobileInput[0].selectionStart < countryCodeLength) {
            loginMobileInput[0].selectionStart = countryCodeLength;
        }
    });`

This works fine, but my problem is that onFocus, everything get's selected anyways!
Handling the focus event matters not -> the selectAll happens afterwards...
Preventing the mouseUp helps somehow, but destroys the normal behavior of deselecting once selected, and does not prevents the select all on the TAB-action...

What do i need to do to prevent or handle this selectAll?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here one example how can you do it, use: keyup, keydown and change

all from jquery

```
$('#phone').keydown( function( e ) {
    if( e.which == 8 )
    {
        if ( $('#phone').val() == $('#country_code').val() )
            return false;
    }
});

$('#phone').keyup( function( e ) {
    if ( $('#phone').val().substr(0,3) != $('#country_code').val() )
        $('#phone').val( $('#country_code').val() + $('#phone').val() );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3L2qytp2/

Comment: Aaah, I forgot to mention... The autocompletion should work... This wants to say, that if for example the +44 is selected by default, and the autocompletion adds a +32 number, the dropdown should select the +32 automatically, while the number should remain... And basicly I've realized all this with timeouts and keyUp/keyDown/select... But on focus, it is possible to select all, and cut/edit it

Comment: I've made a fusion with your code and I've managed to get it working =) So I've accepted your answer! Thx!